# Excel. Growth formula? Seems like a basic task

Tags: microsoft-excel

It seems to me this is a very basic task to achieve, but I'm having a hard time getting it working...

For a period of 36 months, I want to know how many customers I'll have at the end of each month so I can show a growth graph. 
So far so good... just add the previous value with the expected growth, right?

This is where it gets complicated: 
- On *month1* I'll have **X** number of operating stores
- Each month thereafter I'll have **Y** number of new stores where my product is offered 
- For each store, I have a rampup of new customers (5% each month for the first 20 months, so after 20 months, 100% will become customers)

Example of what I'm expecting as a result at *month3* where I start with 5 stores then add 3 stores each month with the rampup: (((5 stores x 5%) + (5 stores x 10%) + (5stores x 15%)) + ((3 stores x 5%) + (3 stores x 10%)) + (3 stores x 5%))

Comment: Wouldn't the first 5 stores only be the last  percentage of 15% and not the others.

Comment: That's correct. It appears that way: (5 stores x 5%) + (5 stores x 10%) + (5stores x 15%).

Comment: I mean in the 3rd month if you started with 5 in  the first month: 5 stores at 15% + 3 stores at 10% + 3 stores at 5%?  With a total of 1.2 stores worth of customers?  This way as you said you would be 100% in month 20 on the first 5 stores 95% on the 3 you got the second month 90 % on the 3 you got the third and so on?  I guess I am misunderstanding how your narrative relates to your equation, why the percentage is compounding.

Comment: ahhh. yes, percentage should not be compounded... as it will eventually be 100% in month 20. What is compounding is the number of stores as you open new stores every month...
so the correct thing would be 5x15%+3x10%+3x5%....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little thinking, but here is a formula that will give you what you want:

```
=MIN($B$1*($B$3*$B$4),$B$1)+SUMPRODUCT($B$2*($B$3 *ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(INT(1/$B$3),$B$4-1)))))+MAX($B$2*($B$4-((INT(1/$B$3))+1)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @scott I'll give it a try... 
Any Idea on how to build it on a month-by-month basis? 
I'm figuring to leave B1..B3  fixed  (like $B$1) and then run the formula 36 times across each month. Is that practical?

Comment: Sure just list the months down a column then put change the references From $B$4 to the Column you put the months.  For example if you put your list starting in C1 to C36 just put the formula in D1 and Change all the `$B$4` to `$C1`  Then copy/drag the formula down the column. @heboma

Comment: Super. 
I'm finding a bit of a hassle using the formula across rows instead of columns, as it givms me the #REF! error. Maybe its because of the INDIRECT?

Comment: then instead of `$C1` you would want `C$1` @heboma.  The month 1 will give a ref error just put `=B1*B3` in that cell then use the other formula from month 2 on.

Comment: Looking to improve the formula, is there a way to easily cap the penetration rate? I mean instead of reaching 100% be it a **Z%**? I've already changed  it so the number of stores can vary month by month.

Comment: At this point you are asking a new question that deserves a new post as it will require a new formula.  Easy is relative.  It would take a while to rethink the formula above.